# Simplest way to add built-in commands to an custom add-in

Tags: arcgis-10.0, arcobjects, add-in

Currently in  *Config.esriaddinx* I have

```
<Button id="my_UniqueID" class="MyWrapperClass" caption="My Caption"
         image="Images\My_Image.png" ...> </Button>
```

and then I implement MyWrapperClass with:

```
protected override void OnClick()
{
    UID uid = new UIDClass();
    uid.Value = "esriArcMapUI.GraphicsToFeaturesCommand";

    ICommandItem cmd = ArcMap.Application.Document.CommandBars.Find(uid);
    if (cmd != null)
        cmd.Execute();
}
```

I'd like to just have the following in *Config.esriaddinx*

```
<Button id="esriArcMapUI.GraphicsToFeaturesCommand" />
```

and have the built-in command object do all the work for me.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes it is possible to *reference* a built-in command (button) on a custom menu/toolbar (What I really need to do).  It is not possible to *redefine* a built-in command (What I was trying to do).

One can reference a built-in command on a custom menu/toolbar like this.

```
    <Menu id="my_id" caption="Cool_tools">
      <Items>
        <Button refID="my_custom_button" />
        <Button refID="esriArcMapUI.GraphicsToFeaturesCommand" />
        ...
      </Items>
    </Menu>
```

And similarly for a tool on a toolbar.

Comment: Still, this is very useful and good to know. +1